# MS Access Text Box

Tags: database, ms-access, office365

Access for Microsoft 365.
Form design-->Text box.

I have created a text box but when I save the same text it is displayed in all the individual records.
How do I get a different text for each individual record?
For example:
I have 50 different customer records.
I have a label titled fruit fo all 50 records.
If I write in the text box 'apple' in the first record label all 50 records will have the same text box 'apple'
How do I achieve to have different fruits for each records?

Answer (score 1):

Add that "fruit" field to the table, then bind your textbox to this field - like the other fields you display on the form.

Set the *ControlSource* property of the textbox to: YourNameOfTheFruitField

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am not skilled enough.
Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Design mode
Right click on the textbox field just created.
On the right I have property sheet
Data/Control source
Then what should I do?
Which option should I choose?

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thanks but in the ControlSource property  drop down menu I don't have a 'YourNameOfTheFruitField' value because I didn't create it previously and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Open the table in design view and add the field. This is so very basic, so you should look up a tutorial or guide like "Beginning with Microsoft Access".

Comment: The problem is that I did not make the DB and the person who did is no longer available.
I have never used MS Access.
I just need to add a TextBox field for all the records so even looking at a tutorial I wouldn't know where to find the information I need.
However I opened the table in design view and saw "add existing field" if I click it I get a list of all the fields already in the DB.
I don't need to add the TextBox from the existing list, I want to create a new one.

Comment: You have opened the form in design view; it may have an _existing field_ to add. Open the _table_ in design view. However, this is OT here, as SO is all about coding. You may visit another forum better suited for your case like _Experts Exchange_ or _UtterAccess_.